# PyDrake ImportError: cannot import name 'DiscreteContactSolver' from 'pydrake.all'

Tags: python, drake

Trying to follow the [Force Control examples from the Manipulation textbook](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Manipulation-ac8201a1-470a-4c77-afd0-2cc45bc229ff/project/09-Force-Control-87d8044f-3eb2-4f25-b52f-f51a5eca68b7/%2Fforce.ipynb)
however I'm running into this issue at the beginning:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'DiscreteContactSolver' from 'pydrake.all'

I've checked my installation and I'm at drake 1.9.0.
The online pydrake documentation says that the DiscreteContactSolver is under pydrake.multibody.plant but even specifying that path does not help. I've also had this issue with AddWeld() but got around that with plant.WeldFrames(). Is the online documentation out of date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drake v1.9.0 does not contain python bindings for `DiscreteContactSolver`.  The website API documentation current reflects the nightly build, not the stable release.

The pydrake bindings for DiscreteContactSolver were added in [#18214](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/18214) on October 30th. The pydrake [release 1.9.0](https://pypi.org/project/drake/1.9.0/) was approximately three weeks prior, on October 10th.

To use DiscreteContactSolver, you'll need to use the nightly release (until v1.10.0 comes out):

- https://drake.mit.edu/pip.html#nightly-releases
- https://drake.mit.edu/docker.html#nightly-releases
- https://drake.mit.edu/installation.html

Comment: Thank you for this information, I did not know the textbook examples were so up-to-date as to require the nightly releases.

Comment: The downside of the nightlies of course is that they sometimes have bugs.  If you're using Deepnote, we just noticed that docker images 20221108 and 20221109 are broken.  Please use 20221107 (or earlier) or 20221110 (or later) if you're on Deepnote.